# Powershell Start-job new window run as administrator

Tags: powershell, uac, start-job

I have script which write some COMMAND to another script and start them in new window with Start-Job command (I really need that). $cred is credential of local administrator. Main script started from powershell windows which opened "run as administrator" (as machine administrator). COMMAND need to open with machine administrator account (like new window open with "run as administrator"). BUT new window open only with local administrator rights. I search in the internet for information to round this issue, but failed. May be someone know how i can run new window with start-job command with machine administrator ("run as administrator")?

```
$ScriptFile = "$env:TEMP\ScriptBlock.ps1"
Write-Output "`$ProfileApp = <COMMAND> | Out-File $ScriptFile -Width 300
$PJob = Start-Job -Name PJob -Credential $cred -FilePath $ScriptFile -Verbose -InitializationScript {Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell} | Wait-Job
Receive-Job -Name PJob -Verbose
Remove-Job -Name PJob -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable err
Remove-Item -Path "$env:TEMP\ScriptBlock.ps1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might be what you are looking for:
[A self elevating PowerShell script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/virtual_pc_guy/a-self-elevating-powershell-script)